# How to reduce the size of ImageMagick WASM if only want one feature?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

The ImageMagick library is great, it has a thousand options to edit images and convert them into many formats (more than 100). However, I only want to use **one feature** of ImageMagick from a static website (no server), which changes the format from PNG to EPS.

Using `@imagemagick/magick-wasm` I already get it with this function:

```js
async function pngToEps(pngBlob) {
  const imageMagick = await import('@imagemagick/magick-wasm');   
  const imageBuffer = await pngBlob.arrayBuffer();
  const imgData = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer)
  
  await imageMagick.initializeImageMagick();

  return new Promise((res) => {
    imageMagick.ImageMagick.read(imgData, (image) => {
      image.format = imageMagick.MagickFormat.Eps;
      image.write((epsImg) => res(new Blob([epsImg])));
    });
  });
}
```

It works in the browser, but the WASM occupies **~17MB**... Too much... I would like instead of importing the whole library just the feature I need.

Is there a tool to prune a WASM and convert it to a smaller WASM running the feature we want to keep? Or another smaller library to convert a PNG to EPS in the browser? Thank you so much!